# How to expandable tree selected then textbox display data in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

How to expandable tree selected then textbox display data in AngularJS?

JS:

```
    var appBo = angular.module('appBo', []);
        appBo.directive('tree', function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'E', 
            replace: true, 
            scope: {
              t: '=src'   
            },    
            template: '<ul><branch ng-repeat="c in t.children" src="c"></branch></ul>'    
          };
        })

        appBo.directive('branch', function($compile) {
          return {
            restrict: 'E', 
            replace: true, 
            scope: {
              b: '=src' 
            },    

            template: '<li><a>{{ b.name }}</a></li>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

              var has_children = angular.isArray(scope.b.children);

              // Manipulate HTML in DOM
              if (has_children) {        
                element.append('<tree src="b"></tree>');

                // recompile Angular because of manual appending
                $compile(element.contents())(scope); 
              }

              // Bind events
              element.on('click', function(event) {
                  event.stopPropagation();          

                  if (has_children) {
                    element.toggleClass('collapsed');
                  }
              });      
            }
          };
        })

        appBo.controller('TreelistController', function ($scope) {
          $scope.categories = {
            children: [
              {
                name: "Item A",
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "Item A-1",

                    children: [
                      {
                        name: "Item A-1-1"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Item A-1-2"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Item A-2",
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: "Item A-2-1"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Item A-2-2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                name: "Item B",
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "Item B-1",
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: "Item B-1-1"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Item B-1-2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
               {
                name: "Item C",
                children: [
                  {
                    name: "Item C-1",
                    children: [
                      {
                        name: "Item C-1-1"
                      },
                      {
                        name: "Item C-1-2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          };    
        });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app='appBo'> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><p>
        <h1>Angular JS-Tree</h1>
            <div ng-app="appBo" ng-controller="TreelistController">         
                <p>Catagory</p>
                <tree src="categories"></tree>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to improve code display here.

Comment: Hi, do you want to create a new custom directive for data tree? You can refer this link [link](https://github.com/abhilashpullelil/my_tree_directive). If you have any specific issue, please feel to contact me. I am here to help you.